# Chrome error when i try interact with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am making an internal tool for to modify an iframe but chrome throw an error.

This is my html:

```
<iframe src="https://sportmaniacs.com/es/services/inscription/mitja-marato--10k-ciutat-de-tarragona-2019/5d63d5fc-bb64-4c09-98d6-7440ac1f1c51"
    frameborder="0"
></iframe>
```

This is my js:

```
  const iframe =  this.iframe.nativeElement
  if ( (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document).readyState === 'complete' ) {
    iframe.onload = this.onIframeLoad.bind(this)
  } else {
    if (iframe.addEventListener) {
      iframe.addEventListener('load', this.onIframeLoad.bind(this), true)
    } else if (iframe.attachEvent) {
      iframe.attachEvent('onload', this.onIframeLoad.bind(this))
    }
  }

  function onIframeLoad() {
    const base64String = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
    console.log(this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body.children[1].currentSrc)
    console.log(base64String)
  }
```

But this code:
`iframe.contentWindow.document`

Thow this error:
`Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:5200" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

Could I skip the error someway? perhaps with a plugin or something...

Comment: This is a basic security feature. To access a cross-origin iframe, the serveur must set headers to allow you to do so. If your not the owner of the website, you cannot do much about it.

Comment: yes, I know. But this is an internal tool for workers team, I am sure that this could doing with an extension, supress secure of chrome or with other browser....

Comment: You could proxy their site through your own and the required headers on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround has been described here: [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

It only works if you own both websites.

Otherwise you can disable the same-origin-policy in your browser, but like it says, it will only affect your browser.